# Save PNG to Disk, but save file path to Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiimage

There might be a duplicate question on here, but I searched and couldn't find an answer.

I have an app that accepts a signature from the user and saves that signature as a .png file. Here's the code I use:

```
-(void)saveSignature

{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    signature = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(signature);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"signature.png"];
    [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
}
```

This code works great. It saves a .png of the signature in my application's documents folder. What I need to do is save the file path to my Core Data model and access it via. Core Data.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? All you need to do is assign the filePath to a string property of a managed object and save the context.

Comment: That's what I was assuming, but how do I access it? If I call it, won't Core Data return a String?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if you have anything else in Core Data. If you do, simply create an `imagePath` attribute on your model, and assign the path to the document into it. Then, simply load the image into the UIImage when you need to, based on the model, using UIImage's `imageWithContentsOfFile:` method.

If you don't already have Core Data in place and models generated, well, you really need to learn Core Data, and StackOverflow might not be the best place for that. [This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) might be a good place to start.

My first piece of advise when it comes to Core Data is to use the [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) library, which makes the general use of Core Data much, much easier.

Comment: Thanks. I have Core Data set up and I have 1 entity with 3 attributes. I wanted to add a 4th for an image. I'll assume I add the imagePath as a String. Thanks for the help!